# How to contain images in react material ui CardMedia component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, contains

Certain images are much bigger and parts of them are hidden:[image]

The closest I get in getting it right was by playing around with width and height:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    ...

    media: {
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        margin: 'auto',
    },

    ...
}));

const Brands = (props) => {
    ...

    return <div style={{ marginTop: props._marginTop }}>
        <Grid container justify='center'>
            <Grid item xs={10}>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    {brands.map((brand, i)=> {
                        return <Grid item key={i} lg={3} xs={12}>
                                <Card>
                                    <CardMedia
                                        className={classes.media}
                                        image={brand.image.length > 0 ? brand.image : knightdemon}
                                        title={brand.name}
                                    />
                                    <CardContent>
                                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                            {brand.name.toUpperCase()}
                                        </Typography>
                                        <Typography 
                                            onClick={()=>setFlip(true)} 
                                            className={classes.description} 
                                            gutterBottom variant="body2" 
                                            component="p"
                                        >
                                            DESCRIPTION
                                        </Typography>
                                    </CardContent>
                                </Card>
                        </Grid>
                    })}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </div>
}

export default Brands;
```

Height looks good on all of them, the problem is with width and if I increase it it affects height as well.
How do I contain them in the given space so they look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fit image in `CardMedia`, add props `component="img"` like:

```
<CardMedia
    className={classes.media}
    image={brand.image.length > 0 ? brand.image : knightdemon}
    title={brand.name}
    component="img"
/>
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: This worked like magic thanks a lot @Giovanni. I had to also get rid of height in media class, but yeah that did it.

Comment: @LukasLukeStateczny happy to ear that. Ciao Ciao =)

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito this works well. Thank you for your answer! I was using a Link as a component so I could click on the image to navigate to the item, but that screwed dimensions of the image. Any idea how to implement sort of link now that component is img? thanks!

Comment: @MurphyAdam No problem, happy to help you. To click on `CardMedia`, you could use `onClick` prop : `onClick={() => console.log("navigate to the item")}`.